# "JavaScript Libraries" missing from IntelliJ 14

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm following this support article https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-angularjs.html and the "JavaScript Libraries" section is missing from the Settings pane of IntelliJ 14. Anyone know where I can access the JavaScript Libraries in IntelliJ?

[image]

Comment: Oh god, what OS is that?

Comment: @mvd Windows ME. -- just kidding, Server 2008r2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the "JavaScript Support Plugin", see the Prerequisites here -- https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/javascript-specific-guidelines.html. The documentation may be out of date because you can only get it in the Ultimate Edition, it's marketed as having Web development support and it's not free unfortunately.

Comment: From what I've read the Community Edition isn't able to install the standard JavaScript Support plugin.